# Bulk loading of Wikidata dump in Virtuoso

Tags: rdf, wikidata, virtuoso

I am trying to load the *truthy* dump of Wikidata into Virtuoso opensource version 7.2 using the bulk loading feature explained in http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoader

I used the dump `latest-truthy.nt.bz2` which is in `nt` format:

Steps:

1. Add the directory containing Wikidata to *DirsAllowed* in `virtuoso.ini`.
2. Create the described `global.graph` file and write the uri in it `http://wikidata.org`
3. Opened `isql`
4. Using specify the files to load `ld_dir('directory_of_the_dump','*.nt','http://wikidata.org');`
5. run the loader: `rdf_loader_run(log_enable=>3);`

The error appears in the log file as:

> File '..../wikidata/latest-truthy.nt error 42000 RDFGE: RDF box with a geometry RDF type and a non-geometry content

Is this a problem in the data or in the configuration?

Comment: the geo data and maybe how Virtuoso parses it: https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/195 and https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/274 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230999/loading-geospatial-rdf-in-virtuoso

Comment: I suggest you follow up to [this related issue on the Virtuoso project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/295), or [create your own new issue there](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/).